# How to receive multiple messages of kafka topics in parallel with spark streaming DStream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

i used a mysql CDC(changing data capturing) system which can capture new records inserted into mysql tables and sent to kafka with one topic per one table. Then in spark streaming, i want to receive multiple messages of kafka topics in parallel with spark streaming DStream API for further processing of these changing data from these mysql tables.

CDC is setup just fine and messages are tested received OK for all tables by kafka-consume-topic.sh. But in spark streaming, i can only got 1 table's messages received. but if only 1 topic/stream created in the application one by one for all tables' test, all tables seperately are tested ok to be read by spark streaming. i searched long time for relevant questions, articles and examples in spark github project, no lucky to get solution. there are examples to union non Direct stream, but those spark streaming APIs are old and i hesitate to adopt them doubting later maybe lots of wheel re-inventing works to do.

below are my codes:

```
package com.fm.data.fmtrade

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object TestKafkaSparkStreaming {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var conf=new SparkConf()//.setMaster("spark://192.168.177.120:7077")
      .setAppName("SparkStreamKaflaWordCount Demo")
      .set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "8")
    val ss = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config(conf)
      .appName(args.mkString(" "))
      .getOrCreate()

    val topicsArr: Array[String] = Array(
      "betadbserver1.copytrading.t_trades",
      "betadbserver1.copytrading.t_users",
      "betadbserver1.account.s_follower",
      "betadbserver1.copytrading.t_followorder",
      "betadbserver1.copytrading.t_follow",
      "betadbserver1.copytrading.t_activefollow",
      "betadbserver1.account.users",
      "betadbserver1.account.user_accounts"
    )

    var group="con-consumer-group111" + (new util.Random).nextInt(10000)
    val kafkaParam = Map(
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "beta-hbase02:9092,beta-hbase03:9092,beta-hbase04:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> group,
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",//"latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(ss.sparkContext, Seconds(4))
    //val streams =
      topicsArr.foreach{//.slice(0,1)
      topic =>
        val newTopicsArr=Array(topic)
        val stream=
          KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String,String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String,String](newTopicsArr,kafkaParam))
        stream.map(s =>(s.key(),s.value())).print();
    }
    /*
    val unifiedStream = ssc.union(streams)
    unifiedStream.repartition(2)
    unifiedStream.map(s =>(s.key(),s.value())).print()
    */
    /*
    unifiedStream.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
      rdd.foreachPartition{ partitionOfRecords =>
        partitionOfRecords.foreach{ record =>

        }
      }
    }
    */
    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
  }

}
```

Comment: to supplement, my spark rev is 2.2.0, kafka is 0.10.2.2

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/